# Broken design and and not clearly visible dash in EnhancedDateRangePicker Vaadin 14 component

Tags: components, vaadin, daterangepicker, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

There are two problems that I have using the EnhancedDateRangePicker in Vaadin 14(source: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/date-range-picker):

The design is broken when I add the component somewhere in a layout but that happens only when I add a label. If I don't the design is as expected to be. Here is a screenshot to see what exactly happens - [image]

The other problem is that the dash is not visible clearly in this color(light gray I think). Is there a way to change the color of the dash?

Could you please tell me is there any way to make the design as I mentioned in the above two points?

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Which specific version are you using? can you share an example of how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The latest version - 1.9.0 and the problem you can reproduce if you add the component with a label above the component and will be as In the picture I've uploaded. Example:  
`EnhancedDateRangePicker enhancedDateRangePicker = new EnhancedDateRangePicker("Valid from - Valid to");

HorizontalLayout mainLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
verticalLayout.add(enhancedDateRangePicker);
mainLayout.add(verticalLayout); `

Comment: I've created an issue in the GitHub repo so we can track this issue in there: https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/vcf-date-range-picker-flow/issues/30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It's not the problem with the component, it is actually the Theme which we are using in our projects and the component just overrides the theme styles and that brokes the component. When I put it in a blank page there is no problem. Thanks you all very much for the effort :).